# How to properly initialize objects in objective c with ARC

Tags: objective-c, constructor, initialization, automatic-ref-counting

For many classes there are initXXX methods and typeXXX methods, for example:

```
NSNumber *n1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
NSNumber *n2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

I've read about manual memory management and I think that I understand how those lines are different with manual memory management (second is just shortcut for autoreleased object).

But with ARC I don't understand which API I should use? Should I use only alloc-init pattern because ARC is smart enough to make value autoreleased if necessary and avoid autorelease overhead when value is only used locally? Or ARC can optimize out autorelease and corresponding overhead even when I use something like numberWithInt?

I would like to use second variant when available, because it's shorter and easier to read. But I don't want to introduce performance overhead just for this reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or ARC can optimize out autorelease and corresponding overhead even when I use something like numberWithInt?

It can, even with these convenience factory (so are they called) methods. [Here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/) all is explained well.

So you can use either one.

Comment: and as of clang 3.3, you can use @1 also.

Comment: @danh I'm glad you correctly mentioned the version of Clang (as opposed to "Xcode XYZ". Yes, that's right.